# How to see where the agent is stored. Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

In the rackStore block, functionRack determines where the agent is stored (which can be one of three PalletRacks).

However in the rackPick block , I do not know how to specify the "Pallet rack / Rack system" field, and my search of the examples/handbook/other questions and guessing has been unsuccessful.

If you could help me out, I would be very grateful.

Thanks in advance

[extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrQnU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Put RackSystem block at Main, select all the pallet racks in the block properties. Then, go to RackPick properties, specify the RackSystem block. There are couple of example model: Wholesale Warehouse and Distribution Center, find them in Help - Example Models.